# Form freezes during while loop

Tags: c#, forms, while-loop

I have a piece of code that checks if a certain application is running

```
while (Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length == 0)
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

It will check if the user is running notepad but it makes the form freeze and stop responding after a few seconds. I don't know if there is a better solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you actually want some work done on a thread that's separate from your main UI thread.

The ideal scenario would be to leverage the `BackgroundWorker` object, which will happily run on another thread and not block your UI.

I won't give you a full explanation, as there are plenty of tutorials out there, but you're going to want to do something like:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
```

This creates the `BackgroundWorker` and binds its `DoWork` event to the `workerDoWork` handler we are about to create:

```
 void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
    //Glorious time-consuming code that no longer blocks!
    while (Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length == 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
 }
```

Now start the worker:

```
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Check out this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: The only problem with this is it won't wait for the backgroundworker to finish his job.

Comment: What won't wait? The `BackgroundWorker` object has some additional tricks up its sleeve, but I don't quite understand what it is you are attempting. Look through the tutorial and the documentation, there are additional details in there.

Comment: I call this after they click a launch button, now for it to work notepad has to be open, but now the backgroundworker gets called and the rest of the application is doing it's normal self.

Comment: @badkip - Windows is event-driven, and your program should work that way as well. Don't "wait" for something to happen, react to the status-change.

Answer (score 3):

The form freezes because your code is running on the UI/Main thread.
So because you are Sleeping the thread while notepad is not open then your form will lock up.
If you run your code asynchronously then you move the worker thread away from the UI.
See here for an [C# async overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could always just start an asynchronous task to keep updating the UI

```
Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //This would make the form become responsive every 500 ms
                Thread.Sleep(500); //Makes the async thread sleep for 500 ms
                Application.DoEvents(); //Updates the Form's UI
            }
        });
```

Or this to run it on a different thread

```
Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
while (Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length == 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //Does the while loop every 1000 ms
    }
});
```